# How to set an outside element inside a flex-box

Tags: css, reactjs, user-interface, layout, flexbox

my code is

```
<div className="app-container">
  <div className="border-content">
    <OptionsPanel />
    <TrendingList />
  </div>
  <div className="tweets-list-container">
    <TweetList results={tweets} />
  </div>
</div>
```

and with flexbox is currently displayed in the screen like:

```
OPTIONS-PANEL | TRENDING-LIST | TWEETS-LIST
```

but what i want is

```
OPTIONS-PANEL | TWEETS-LIST | TRENDING-LIST (like the twitter page)
```

Is something that can i do to fix this with CSS? Or i should refactor my JSX code? I did it like that because i'm layouting mobile-first and it looks well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the order is going to be different at different breakpoints, my suggestion would be to have the three components be siblings within a flex container and then use flex-order or flex-grow in order to reorder or stack them as you wish.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order

Comment: I will do that. Thanks!

Comment: @goplay sure! It feels really childish but honestly this tutorial is the best in terms of learning all the magic stuff you can do with flexbox: https://flexboxfroggy.com/.